# capturar el vinculo href con javascript en asp.mvc webgrid

Tags: javascript, html5, asp.net-mvc

tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
<div class="table ">
        @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table highlight hoverable"
                  , columns: new[] {
        grid.Column("Persona"),
        grid.Column("Calificacion"),
        grid.Column("ente",header:"Ente Calificador"),
        grid.Column("Tareas"),
        grid.Column("Descri", header:"Descripción"),
        grid.Column("Fecha",
                    header: "Fecha de Vencimiento",
                    format: p=>p.Fecha.ToShortDateString()),
        grid.Column("Url",header:"Adjunto",format:@<text><a title="Adjunto" href="~/doc/@item.Url#toolbar=0" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons right">library_books</i></a></text>)
                                          })
    </div>
```

y quiero pasar via javascript el valor de href en el vinculo  cuando hago click con el mouse en el mismo. a un modal que detallo abajo. en el atributo src de la etiqueta embed. teniendo en cuenta que el webgrid genere una tabla con registros distintos y enlaces distintos.

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Calificacion</h4>
        <embed src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

como podría hacer esto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si puedes agregar ids al `<a>` y al `<embed>`, puedes hacerlo asi:

```js
document.getElementById("adjunto").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var href = this.getAttribute("href");
  document.getElementById("embed").src = href;
  $("#modal1").modal();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="table ">
        <text><a id="adjunto" title="Adjunto" href="~/doc/@item.Url#toolbar=0" target="_blank"><i class="material-icons right">library_books</i></a></text>
    </div>


<div id="modal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h4>Calificacion</h4>
        <embed id="embed" src="" />
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <a href="#!" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Agree</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hola muchísimas gracias. y para disparar el modal en la misma función que se le podría agregar.?

Comment: Tambien cuando la webgrid genera varias filas distintas con distintos id . se puede saber el id del objeto al que se le hizo click y ahi recien hacer la funcion que me comentaste.

Comment: Para mostrar el modal solo necesitas agregar `$("#modal1").modal();` al final de la funcion.  Ya edite mi respuesta.